# c++ cast vector<Inherited*> to vector<abstract*>

Tags: c++, vector, casting, polymorphism

```
class Interface{};

class Foo: public Interface{};

class Bar{
public:
    vector<Interface*> getStuff();
private:
    vector<Foo*> stuff;
};
```

How do I implement the function `getStuff()`?

Comment: Note that a related problem is that [`Foo**` is not convertible to `Interface**`](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/derivedptrptr-to-baseptrptr.html) and multiple/virtual inheritance could make the conversion from a `Foo*` to a `Interface*` nontrivial.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
vector<Interface*> result(stuff.begin(), stuff.end());
return result;
```

Answer (score 6):

`std::vector<Inherited*>` and `std::vector<abstract*>` are different, and pretty much unrelated, types. You cannot cast from one to the other. But you can `std::copy` or use iterator range constructor as @Grozz says.

#### Edit:

Answering your question in the comments: they are different the same way two classes with members of compatible types are different. Example:

```
struct Foo {
    char* ptr0;
};

struct Bar {
    char* ptr1;
};

Foo foo;
Bar bar = foo; // boom - compile error
```

For that last statement to work you'd need to define an explicit assignment operator like:

```
Bar& Bar::operator=( const Foo& foo ) {
    ptr1 = foo.ptr0;
    return *this;
}
```

Hope this makes it clear.

Comment: can you explain me why they are different? in my point of view semantically every "vector of ptr_to_Inherited" IS also a "vector of ptr_to_abstract"

Comment: for that to be true vector of ptr_to_Inherited would need to inherit from vector of ptr_to_abstract, but std::vector doesn't know it needs to do this and consequently doesn't do it.

Comment: @Mat, you are semantically right, but the C++ norm could not chose to implement that: if you think for instance of a template class Foo that has different specializations for Base and Derived, then it is not possible for the compiler to see how to convert between Foo<Base> and Foo<Derived>...

Answer (score 3):

I am using this. It is not very nice, but fast I think :)

```
vector<Interface*> getStuff()
{
    return *(std::vector<Interface*> *)&stuff;
}
```

And you can also return only reference to the vector with this method

```
vector<Interface*> &getStuff()
{
    return *(std::vector<Interface*> *)&stuff;
}
```

Comment: I think it is a bit dangerous, and it will probably not work if you have multiple inheritance (I would not recommend doing that), but I agree that copying the vector is also ugly (but safer...)