# C++ Reference to vector of derived types

Tags: c++, vector, polymorphism

I have numerous objects implementing an interface called `ExposesCommands`.

```
class ExposesCommands
{
    virtual bool get_command_results(std::string command, std::vector<std::string> &results) = 0;
};
typedef std::unique_ptr<ExposesCommands> ExposesCommands_ptr;
```

Commands are exposed via a template class:

```
template <typename T>
class ExposedCommands : public ExposesCommands
{
private:
    static std::map<const char*, std::string T::*, cmp_str> exposed_cmds;

public:
    virtual bool get_command_results(std::string command, std::vector<std::string> &results);
}
```

Now, I am trying to add sub-commands. Sub-commands will link to sub-objects that implement the commands. The way I would like to add them is like so:

```
template <typename T>
class ExposedCommands : public ExposesCommands
{
private:
    static std::map<const char*, std::string T::*, cmp_str> exposed_cmds;
    static std::map<const char*, std::vector<ExposesCommands_ptr> T::*, cmp_str> exposed_sub_cmds;

public:
    virtual bool get_command_results(std::string command, std::vector<std::string> &results) {
        auto &it = exposed_cmds.find(command.c_str());
        if (it != exposed_cmds.cend()) {
            auto x = std::bind(it->second, std::placeholders::_1);
            std::string data = x(*((T*)this));
            if (data != "") {
                results.push_back(data);
            }
            return true;
        }
        // else check if in exposed_sub_cmds.
            // if so, iterate through vector, call get_command_results
            // on remainder of command name for each sub object, adding
            // its result to the vector of results.
            // return true
        //
        return false;
    }
}
```

I have objects like this implementing the interface (building of the maps is not shown here):

```
class ObjectA : public ExposesCommands<ObjectA>
{
public:
    std::string cmd_x;  // command X
    std::string cmd_y;  // command Y
}
typedef std::unique_ptr<ObjectA> ObjectA_ptr;

class ObjectB
{
public:
    std::string cmd_z;  // command Z
    std::vector<ObjectA_ptr> my_as;  // 'ObjectA' sub commands
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work because I can't assign a `&std::vector<ObjectA_ptr>` to a `std::vector<ExposesCommands_ptr> T::*`.

Is there any way to get around this? Or a better approach to this problem?

Comment: could someone enlighten me what `std::string T::*` is?

Comment: It's a member pointer - specifically a pointer to a (non-static) member of T that is of type std::string.

Comment: "Unfortunately, *this* doesn't work" - what's this? I think you've failed to post the relevant code.

Comment: This doesn't work: ```std::map<const char*, std::vector<ExposesCommands_ptr> ObjectB::*, cmp_str> m; m["AS"] = &ObjectB::my_as;```

Comment: No way to get around the non-assignability, see for example [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891529/c-cast-vectorinherited-to-vectorabstract?rq=1). You don't show enough (and what you show is incomplete, like the `ExposesCommand` interface missing its virtual function, or the `exposed_sub_cmds` map having the value type value instead of ptr-to-member) to judge whether there is a better approach, but making my_as a vector-of-ptr-to-base might work. The C++ standard has no guarantee pointer-to-based and pointer-to-derived for the same instance are represented identically.

Comment: Thanks Michael. You're right that making the vector on ObjectB a pointer to the base class instead of derived would work. The downside to that is that all of my sub-objects would have to be continually cast to their appropriate derived class for use outside of the command interface.

Comment: I've added an example implementation of the virtual method. The goal is basically to expose class attributes to the user via mapping them to strings, and some exposed attributes are on sub classes to the main class.

Comment: I am sorry, I did not ask for `ExposedCommand::get_command_result`, but mentioned that the base interface `ExposesCommand` misses the (pure) virtual declaration of that function.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize your problem: You have a base class and some derived classes

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base();
};
class Derived1 : public Base;
class Derived2 : public Base;
```

You need to store a collection of pointers (for ownership management you chose to use `std::unique_ptr`, which seems wise) to `Derived1` objects in a way that it can be used by code that doesn't know `Derived1` exists, and only wants to use properties of `Base`, but also do not want to lose the property that this specific collection of `Base` objects actually contains `Derived1` objects only. This is a kind of *type erasure*, as the runtime behaciour of the collection should not depend on whether it stores `Base`, `Derived1` or `Derived2` objects (or even a mixture of it, so that property gets erased), yet at compile time, you don't want to write all those ugly downcasts (and you want the compiler to verify you only downcast objects from a container you statically know that it does only contain `Derived1` objects). Be aware that if you are going to store pointers to `Derived1` in `std::unique_ptr<Base>`, it is **absolutely necessary** that `Base` has a virtual destructor.

I don't know any ready-made solution for this off-hand (it couldn't find something skimming over the Boost libraries tagged Container, too), but I can show you how reach that goal yourself. You need a template, to get different compile-time types (just as `std::vector` is a template), which internally stores the data in a fixed type. So something like this:

```
typedef std::unique_ptr<Base> Base_ptr;
template <typename T>
class BaseVector {
public:
    const std::vector<Base_ptr> &
        as_baseclass_vector() const
    {
        return backing_;
    }
private:
    std::vector<Base_ptr> backing_;
};
```

Note that as_baseclass_vector does return a *const* reference to the raw vector, because the result must not be used to insert objects of the wrong type (e.g. pointers to `Derived2` objects) into a `CommandVector` instantiated for `Derived1`. This is only half the way to go, the other half is sadly reimplementing the standard library container concept on this vector-wrapper, along this:

```
template<typename T>
void CommandVector::push_back(std::unique_ptr<T> obj)
{
    backing_.push_back(std::move(obj));
}
```

or, more importantly and interestingly:

```
template<typename T>
const T* BaseVector::operator[](size_t index) const
{
    return static_cast<T*>(backing_[index]);
}
```

Note that this `operator[]` does not return a reference-to-`unique_ptr`, as it could only return a reference to a `unique_ptr<Base>`, because that is what is stored in the backing vector. If it created a tempory `unique_ptr` to `T`, it would have to remove the ownership from the vector - you definitely would not want that! The result has been declared const, because it returns a copy instead of the usual reference, and modifying the return value (which is now forbidden) does *not* modify the object in the vector, opposed to what users expect. You would have to reimplement all the other methods (iterators would get quite interesting, but probably can be based on `boost::transform_iterator`) yourself if you chose to go this route.